# How to install new apk having all the permissions and using FileProvider?

Tags: android

I update my app when it is an old version since it compares the version with a server's last app version(Firebase). So I use Download Manager and I use File provider with all the necessary, the thing is that when it downloads the intent opens it but it closes immediately and the user cannot install the update. It doesn't throw an error It just opens and closes very fast. The download works, it is just the intent to open it.
The manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission  android:name=" android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

The Provider:

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.multilevel.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

The Intent:

```
  if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            var columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)

            if(DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cursor.getInt(columnIndex)){

                var uriString=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))
                var file=File(uriString)
                println(file)
                val f = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!,context!!.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",file)

                var pantallaInstall=Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

                pantallaInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                pantallaInstall.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                pantallaInstall.setDataAndType(f,"application/vnd.android.package-archive")
                context?.startActivity(pantallaInstall)


                Log.e("msj Descarga", "sin problemas")
                Toast.makeText(context, "Descargado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use uriString. That's your uri. Throw away File class and FileProvider. You use them wrong.

Comment: pantallaInstall.type=uriString  like that??? it throws an error  Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.multilevel/files/storage/Naturezavital-6.apk flg=0x1 }

Comment: No not like that of course.

Comment: can you tell me please I am learning this by my own and documentation is not clear

Comment: Replace f by uriString. They are both uries and i said not to use FileProvider who gave you f. So use uriString instead. Well not the string itself but that uri.

Comment: pantallaInstall.data = Uri.parse(uriString) like that?